# setTimeout + animate returning Unexpected identifier?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
  setTimeout(function()
    $('.golden').animate({
      opacity: "1",
      top: "84px"
    }, 'slow');
  }, 1000 );
```

It returns `Unexpected identifier`.

But if I just do this:

```
    $('.golden').animate({
      opacity: "1",
      top: "84px"
    }, 'slow');
```

it works.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have the correct syntax. Use this :

```
   setTimeout(function() { // <= you were missing { to open the function block
    $('.golden').animate({
      opacity: "1",
      top: "84px"
    }, 'slow');
   }, 1000 );
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry I  don't know what's wrong with my brain today.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax issue

use

```
setTimeout(function() 
{ $('.golden').animate({  opacity: "1", top: "84px" }, 'slow'); }, 
1000 );
```